# Android locationmanager returning null

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am using Android location manager to find device location:

```
locManager.getLastKnownLocation
```

I haven't implemented LoationListener, and it was working fine.
But I reset location settings of my device, and getLastKnownLocation started returning null, for both network and gps.

I need device location just once, not regular updates. So how to get around this problem without need to implement LoationListener

Comment: As you did reset, cached last location is set to null. Now you get when system does check for location, Please open once Google Maps application it will start working.

Comment: But if app user faces this, then do I need to convey to user the workaround somehow?